# Ignore blank variable return from qx

Tags: regex, perl, iptables

I'm having difficulty with one little bit of my code.

```
open ("files","$list");
while (my $sort = <files>) {
  chomp $sort;
  foreach my $key (sort keys %ips) {
    if ($key =~ $sort) {
      print "key $key\n";
      my $match =qx(iptables -nL | grep $key 2>&1);
      print "Match Results $match\n";
      chomp $match;
      my $banned = $1 if $match =~ (/(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/);
      print "Banned Results $banned\n";
      if ($key =~ $banned) {
        print "Already banned $banned\n";
      } else {
        system ("iptables -A INPUT -s $key -j DROP");
        open my $fh, '>>', 'banned.out';
        print "Match Found we need to block it $key\n";
        print $fh "$key:$timestamp\n";
        close $fh;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So basically what I'm doing is opening a list of addresses 1 per line.

Next I'm sorting down my key variable from another section of my script and matching it with my list, if it matches then it continues on to the if statement.

Now with that matched key I need to check and see if its blocked already or not, so I'm using a qx to execute iptables and grep for that variable. If it matches everything works perfectly.

If it does not match, in other words my `iptables -nL | grep $key` returns a blank value instead of moving on to my else statement it "grabs" that blank value for $match and continues to execute.

For the life of me I can't figure out how to strip that blank value out and basically show it as no return.

I know there are modules for iptables etc however I have to keep this script as generic as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, when `iptables` returns no results, `$banned` is left at its default value of `undef`.  Used as a regex, $banned matches every string, so your condition:

```
if ($key =~ $banned) {
```

always matches.  I think what you meant to write was probably

```
if ($key eq $banned) {
```

which will fail if either `$banned` is `undef` (because `$matched` was empty or didn't match the regex) or if the IP address you pulled out with the regex was somehow different from `$key`.

If you're confident that the first IP in the `iptables` result will be the same as `$key` then you could simplify your condition to just

```
if ($match =~ /(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/) {
```

Comment: That did the trick, just simplified it down and that works. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put the entire output from `iptables -nL` into an array and `grep` it using Perl. That way you will be calling the utility only once, and it is easy to detect an empty list.

If you write

```
my @iptables = qx(iptables -nL);
```

at the top of your code, then you can query this output by

```
my @match = grep /\b$key\b/, @iptables;
```

and if there are no records that contain the IP address then a subsequent

```
if (@match) { ... }
```

will fail.

There are a few other problems with your code. Firstly, you *must always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program, and declare all variables at their first point of use. This will uncover many simple errors that you may otherwise easily overlook, and applies especially if you are asking for help with your code.

Your `open` call should look like

```
open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
```

together with

```
while (my $sort = <$fh>) { ... }
```

And you seem to have missed the point of hashes. There is no need to read through all of the keys in a hash looking for a match, as the hash elements can be accessed directly with `$ips{$sort}`. If the value returned is `undef` then the element doesn't exist, or you can explicitly check for its existence with `if (exists $ips{$sort}) { ... }`.

I cannot help further as I have no access to a platform that provides `iptables`. If you need more help then please post some output from the utility.

Comment: Thanks for your insight, I'll re-work my code to take proper advantage of the hash, I'm by no means a great programmer. Just know enough to be dangerous :)